# Resizing a List to fit a new Length

Tags: c#, list

Suppose you have a list defined as:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>{"Cat","Dog","Bird","Badger"};
```

Now, suppose you wanted to write a generic function that could take that list and change the length of it. So if you're subtracting the length to make the list smaller, it would truncate the items within the list, or if the length is longer, it would copy the contents of the List and then add new additional indices to it.

A bigger length parameter would result in:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>{"Cat","Dog","Bird","Badger","","","","",""};
```

while a smaller length would result in:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>{"Cat","Dog"};
```

Assuming that no deep copying needed to be done, how could a function like this be written?

Comment: You can `.Add()` and `.Remove()` from a `List<T>` as much as you like.  It handles the "resizing" of the underlying data structure internally.  It's not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: @David I'm aware of how a List resizes, that is not the question that I am asking. My question is, if you were given a length that the List needed to be, how would you shrink or grow the List to fit the new length?

Comment: Well, in order to call `.Add()` to a list X times, one can loop from 0 to X and call `.Add()` within that loop.

Comment: @David And if the function needed to size it downwards, while copying indices that are still within the new range?

Comment: Call `.Remove()` in a loop, starting from the last index?  Or copy to a new list from the first index to the new size?

Comment: @David So, can you demonstrate what the logic for such a function would look like? Here's what I have so far: https://pastebin.com/tpTXvyaB

Comment: If the new size is the same, do nothing, else if the new size is larger, loop over the difference adding the default value, else if the new size is smaller just call `.Take()` with the new size and assign it back to the list.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify you want to resize it to a _specific length_. This is unclear, as evidenced by two out of three answers you received so far (one of which was deleted).

Comment: @Kroltan I will edit my question, sorry for the ambiguity of it.

Comment: @Kroltan I hope my new edit is more helpful.

Comment: Yes it is! Upvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) and [`RemoveRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx), which is better than looping with `Add` and/or `RemoveAt`:

```
public static void PaddedResize<T>(
    List<T> list,
    int size,
    T padding = default(T)
) {
    // Compute difference between actual size and desired size
    var deltaSize = list.Count - size;

    if (deltaSize < 0) {
        // If the list is smaller than target size, fill with `padding`
        list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(padding, -deltaSize));
    } else {
        // If the list is larger than target size, remove end of list
        list.RemoveRange(size, deltaSize);
    }
}
```

This works for immutable, referentially transparent, or struct types, but for the garden variety class, it will pad the list with the same element over and over, which might be non-ideal. To fix that, take a factory function that creates the padding instead:

```
public static void PaddedResize<T>(
    List<T> list,
    int size,
    Func<T> paddingFactory // Changed parameter to a factory function
) {
    // Compute difference between actual size and desired size
    var deltaSize = list.Count - size;

    if (deltaSize < 0) {
        // If the list is smaller than target size, fill with the result of calling `paddingFactory` for each new item
        list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(0, -deltaSize).Select(_ => paddingFactory()));
    } else {
        // If the list is larger than target size, remove end of list
        list.RemoveRange(size, deltaSize);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nevermind! it was an issue on my end. Everything looks great! https://imgur.com/a/6wNdr Thank you for taking the time to help me with this!

Comment: @Krythic Glad it worked! Now if you could just rephrase your question a bit more clearly for future readers to understand it better, it would be great!

Comment: Now just make it an extension method and you're set! :)

Comment: @RufusL It's probably just my code style, but I usually reserve extension methods for pure operations, not to methods that mutate the operand. But surely is doable if desired!

Comment: Just found a bug with this though. If you pass in 'new YourObject()' as the padding parameter, it creates one instance and fills the List with it. So, editing any index in the list will be editing multiple references to the same object. Is there an elegant fix to this?

Comment: @Krythic Well, it's not a bug with the function. Parameters are evaluated before being passed to the function. What you can do is modify the method to take a factory function that returns a padding, that way you can call it every time yielding different objects. I'll edit the answer

Comment: I made a temporary fix for this just by inlining the function into the class I'm using and making it non-generic with Add(new MyObject) instead of AddRange.

Answer (score -2):

You may want to create some `ListUtils` class and write static generic functions there. In case you want a new list containing needed items

```
static class Listutils 
{
     public static List<T> Shrink<T>(List<T> src, Predicate<T> predicate) 
     {
         if (src == null || src.Count == 0) 
              return null;

         List<T> newList = new List<T>();
         foreach(T item in src) 
         {
            if (predicate(item))
                       newList.Add(item);   
         }

         return newList;
     }
}
........somewhere in your program 
  List<string> list = new List<string>{"Cat","Dog","Bird","Badger","Snake"};

  // select only Cat, Dog and Bird
  List<string> shrinked = ListUtils.Shrink(list, (name) => delegate 
  {
     return (name == "Cat" || name == "Dog" || name == "Bird");
  });
```

Comment: That just sounds like [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx). You never add items if the list is shorter.

Comment: yes, but Where clause only selects item by predicate, but he needs a new list of values he wants to select

Comment: `list.Where(predicate).ToList()` then. Still, the OP needs to also _add_ items if the list is shorter than a length.

Comment: The question is very vague though, it's OK :)

Comment: @Kroltan I was trying my best to explain the situation. It's a hard question to describe. Feel free to edit my question if you like! =)